# How can I analyze data split by data in a single column in r?

Tags: r

First off, I know this heading sounds incredibly weird but I simply cannot find better phrasing, which is probably why I can't find it in previously asked question.

What I had wanted to know is how could I analyze, such as the correlation between an independent variable and a Dependent Variable, but seeing for example the correlation between only males first, then only females (Of course I have gender as a column in the data frame.

This of course isn't limited to correlations.  I want to know, just in general what is the best (and easiest if possible) way to do so.

Many Thanks

Comment: How does your data look like? What is its structure?

Answer (score 0):

This is a good use case for the package dplyr

```
library(dplyr)

# g will introduce a correlation for men but not women.
g <- c(rnorm(50),rep_len(0,50)) 
df<-data.frame(gender=rep(c('male','female'),each=50),
               x = rnorm(100) + g,
               y = rnorm(100) + g)

group_by(df,gender) %>% summarise(cor(x,y))

#>  gender   cor(x, y)
#>1 female -0.08525595
#>2   male  0.47967004
```

The dplyr function `group_by` groups the data on the listed fields (gender in this case) `%>%` passes the grouped data.frame to `summarise` which calculates the correlation (or whatever statistic) within groups within that data.frame

Since `summarise` only works for functions that return a single value (like `mean`, `sd`,`cor`, etc), for functions that return values that aren't length 1, then you can use the split-then-lapply style like so:

```
lapply(dfs,function(x)lm(x~y,data=x))
```

which will return a list of all the 'lm' objects.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is helping, but it only seems to be in correlations. When I tried it using a linear regression as so gives me the following: 

> group_by(Ehab, AGE) %>% summarise(lm(DV~IV1+IV2+IV3+IV4)) Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) : invalid term in model formula –  user51875 4 mins ago

Comment: summarise only works for funcitons that return a single value (like `mean`, `sd`,`cor`, etc).  See edited response